# Python: Is there any way I can improve or automate any of the methods in the class below?

Tags: python, optimization, automation, jupyter-notebook, preprocessor

The following is a preprocessing script that I am looking to improve. Any suggestions would be helpful - Should I look into adding more methods to split any of the functions and automate anything? How do I go about improving this code? Thanks in advance.

```
class PreprocessData(Base Estimator, TransformerMixin): def __init__(self, df, content_type="Post"):        
    self.X = df
    self.content_type = content_type
# select features = visual labels, categories, description
# lowercase, remove alphanumeric characters, remove stopwords
# flatten visual labels, categories
# name each label group and change dtype to category
# concatenate dataframes (visual labels, categories)
        
# --Helper Functions Below--  
        
def lowercase(self, text):
    return str(text).lower()

def clean_alphanumeric_stopwords(self, text, category=False):
    stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    text = self.lowercase(text)
    tok_text = word_tokenize(text)
    clean_text = [word for word in tok_text if word.isalpha()]
    clean_text = [word for word in clean_text if not word in stop]
    if category:
        return ','.join(clean_text)
    else:
        return ' '.join(clean_text)
   
#def load_data(self):
    #return pd.read_csv('/Users/melodyzap/Downloads/ds_train_jk (public).csv')

def set_index(self):
    return self.X.set_index('Id')

def remove_empty_char(self, text):
    if type(text)==list: 
        while '' in text:
            text.remove('')
    else:
        print(text)
    return text

def fit(self, X):
    return self

def transform(self):
    
    # self.X = self.set_index()
    
    self.X['Categories'] = self.X['Categories'].apply(self.clean_alphanumeric_stopwords, category=True)
    self.X['Visual Labels'] = self.X['Visual Labels'].apply(self.clean_alphanumeric_stopwords, category=True)
    
    self.X['all_category_data'] = self.X['Visual Labels'] + str(',') + self.X['Categories']
    self.X['all_category_data'] = self.X['all_category_data'].str.split(r',',expand=False)
    self.X['all_category_data']  = self.X['all_category_data'].apply(lambda x: self.remove_empty_char(x))
    self.X.drop(labels=['Categories','Visual Labels'],axis=1, inplace=True)

    if self.content_type != "Image":
        self.X['Description'] = self.X['Description'].apply(self.clean_alphanumeric_stopwords)    
        filter_lang = FilterLanguages()
        self.X = filter_lang.transform(self.X)

    return self.X
```

Comment: for starters you don't print inside a class

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex module to clean your some unwanted data with given pattern.:

```py
import re

word="hello_world$$$!'^!'99"
cleaned_word=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', word).strip()
print([cleaned_word])
    >>> ["hello world 99"]
```